# How to send Email verification codes to user in Firebase using Python?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, kivymd

I'm making a `KivyMD` App and I want to send email verification code when an user is registered to the application. I'm using a `firestore` database with `python` for this project. But I don't have an idea to do that. The registration process is

1. User sign up to the application with his email address.
2. an email contains a code (with random numbers - `OTP Code`) should be send to the user's email.
3. After user enters the correct verification code he should be registered in the application.

Can this be done with the way I expected? Or are there other better ways? Please help me Friends. Thank you in advance...

Comment: Do you have a different backend implementation for the email delivery ? are you limited on firebase products or you are willing to include cloud functions ?

Comment: Have you looked at this: https://dev.to/xbudy/firebase-send-email-verification-using-python-32hp

Answer (score 1):

**In order to send verification link on email you have to setup smpt server**

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import auth
import smtplib
s = smtplib.SMTP('protonmail.com', 1025)
s.starttls()
s.login("your email", "pass0")
cred = credentials.Certificate('you_Secret.json')
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)


# creating the user
email = input('Please enter your email address : ')
password = input("Please enter your password : ")

user = auth.create_user(email=email, password=password )
link = auth.generate_email_verification_link(email, action_code_settings=None)
message = link
print(link)
s.sendmail("sender email", "reciever email", message)

# terminating the session
s.quit()
```

**OUTPUT**

> link:`https://hospitile.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=verifyEmail&oobCode=_yM6YyEBt7e5Fyokjpbt4EUMw4eZzAe41n-t2oS-tNYAAAF9eZ-hnQ&apiKey=AIzaSyBJld5O_s09YVHoQ0ci7g3N3S-0DYjuH0U&lang=en`

[image]

**And when you click on that link you will be prompted to new tab below**

[image]

Comment: Hello, how would I go about sending verification emails without having to create a new account each time? For example, a user could have deleted the email. In this scenario, how could the email be resent?

Comment: hey, @jeff the problem which u stated above can be resolved by making a function that would call the SMTP server every time u make an action using the button/link to resend the email but first make sure that the user already has an account authenticated on firebase.

Comment: Would I need to use the same flow as what you have about in your code? That said, it seems like I could inject the code you have above in some area of my API. However, it seems that I would still need a third-party SMTP provider, is that correct?

Comment: probably yes, but if ur making rest API then it is too simple like the framework ur are using for eg node, Django, etc they have preloaded SMTP so u can take that in use, and it would be less complicated too.

Comment: Hahah, yea. I actually just finished implementing this flow with SendGrid. They have their own functionality to handle the SMTP stuff which is really nice, so I didn't even have to use the frameworks built-in stuff.

Comment: that's great good luck

Comment: I am new to this package. Is it safe to provide my password to this package?

Comment: @VineetPandey yahh its safe else u can have it in .env

Answer (score -2):

Have you found the Firebase Python documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#generate_email_verification_link

It has explanations for the necessary functions to generate email verification links.

```
firebase_admin.auth.generate_email_verification_link(email, action_code_settings=None, app=None)
```

Comment: user ask for something to SEND emails, not just get the link.